# MySQL INSERT in PHP no error feedback

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, mysqli

I am trying to input data to MySQL using PHP. Don't know what's wrong. The connection succeeds, no errors but at the end there is not data being written to the database.

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "listings";
$un = $_POST["un"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$des = $_POST["des"];
$quan = $_POST["quantity"];
$specs = $_POST["specs"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$url1 = ".";
$url2 = ".";
$url3 = ".";
$url4 = ".";

$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$un,$pass,$dbname);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Error".mysqli_error);
} else {
    echo "Database connection successfull ".$des;
}

$query = "INSERT INTO items 
    (name,description,quantity,specs,price,url1,url2,url3,url4) VALUES 
    '$name','$des','$quan','$specs','$price','$url1','$url2','$url3','$url4')
";
echo "Hellos";
$exeute_query = mysqli_query($query,$connection);
if(!execute_query){
    die("error ".mysqli_error());
    echo "query error";
} else {
    echo "Query successfull";
}
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Any help?

Comment: Please do not shout! Question is also seeking *"why does this code not work..."*. You should be able to debug your code. Btw you could enable error reporting.

Comment: `if(!execute_query){` you forgot the `$` sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several small mistakes in your code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO items (name,description,quantity,specs,price,url1,url2,url3,url4) VALUES ('$name','$des','$quan','$specs','$price','$url1','$url2','$url3','$url4')";
echo "Hellos";
**$exeute_query** = mysqli_query($query,$connection); // $execute_query instead of $exeute_query
if(!**execute_query**){ //$execute_query instead of execute_query
 die("error ".mysqli_error());
 echo "query error";
}
else{echo "Query successfull";}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Your code breaks at the if statement because no fucntion with that name is found (if you do not use the dollarsign to show it is a variable, php will interpret it as a function. Also, when initiating your variable you forgot a 'c' so make sure to check if you have the correct variable name or php won't find your variable. Now your query will work or give an error message in case of wrong data formats or bad connection. Use code listed below to debug your php in the future.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: I marked your mistakes in comments next to the lines where they reside.